# Updating to iOS 8 has made my SpriteKit game SUPER SLOW

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I updated my iPhone 5 to iOS 8 yesterday and I started playing a game that I developed that has been on the app store for about two months. My game now horribly lags just by upgrading to iOS 8. I have NEVER had any lag problems what so ever in iOS 7 with devices as old as the iPhone 4 running at 60FPS. This is seriously concerning because I don't want my customers experiencing the same issues if they have updated to iOS 8. Any idea on why this is happening?

Edit: I just did some testing and my FPS is still 60 but my nodes are still moving laggishly. In my program, I have my physicsWorld.speed set to 0.05. When I set it higher, the nodes no longer lag. It seems like iOS 8 physicsWorld.speed doesn't work the same as it does in iOS7. I need that speed or else my game doesn't work correctly. I am still investigating if this is the complete issue!

Comment: Apple provide Instruments that can tell you why an app is slow. Run them, investigate the output and post the results here otherwise it's just guessing.

Comment: Happens to me as well. Same code running on iOS8 lags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The physicsWorld.speed property does not work the same way in iOS8 as it does in iOS7. Changing the physicsWorld.velcoity property to a different CGVector gave me the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

As far as my debugging goes at this point, one problem is in

```
enumerateChildNodesWithName: @"XX" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) { ..
```

This call seems to be slow in iOS 8, maybe with good reason, who knows ..

Anyway, I replaced this with a simple loop, something like:

```
for(SKNode *node in [myCustomLayer children])
{
   if ([node.name isEqualToString: @"blabla"] )
   {
   ..
```

and the FPS was back up. Not sure this has solved all problems, but it had an inpact in my game.